# ClosedXML number formatting not working in version 0.102.2

Tags: .net, closedxml

I recently updated to .NET 8.0 from .NET core 3.1 and updated ClosedXML to verison 0.102.2 but the number formatting stopped working any idea what I am doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Formatting doesn't apply the first time when I open the file but as soon as double click on cell the formatting applies so I guess formatting is there but doesn't apply first time.